# Populating one ListView with multiple CursorLoader/Content Provider

Tags: android, listview, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

I have data from two different ContentProviders which I need to populate in ListView/ListViews in a single fragment.

### Option 1 :

Populated a Listview with data from two different CursorLoaders.

### Option 2 :

Yet to try : I can have two Listviews and it should be populated with two different CursorLoaders. But I don't think this is a better option since both ListViews have its own scroll area.

I tried 1st Option by having Custom Cursor adapter inflating based on the cursor Column name.

### Steps followed:

1. Initiated 1st loader & 2nd loader
2. In the OnCreateLoader, based on the loader id, I returned different CursorLoaders
3. In the Custom Cursor adapter's newView method, based on Column name I inflated different layouts
4. Similar to above I did for bindView method
5. In the onLoadFinished method, I had a statement : **adapterObj.swapCursor(data)**
6. In the onLoaderReset method, I do not have any statement.

When I debug, I observed all the items from both the cursors were able to populate. But I also observed once the 1st loader finished it got reset and **only the data in 2nd loader appears**.

What may be the problem(I suspect swapCursor()). Any other suggestions to achieve this are also welcome.

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(TRAILER_LOADER, null, this);
getLoaderManager().initLoader(REVIEW_LOADER, null, this);

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    switch (id){
        case TRAILER_LOADER:
            return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                    MovieDetailsContract.MovieTrailersEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[]{
                            MovieDetailsContract.MovieTrailersEntry._ID,
                            MovieDetailsContract.MovieTrailersEntry.COLUMN_KEY,
                            MovieDetailsContract.MovieTrailersEntry.COLUMN_NAME
                    },
                    MovieDetailsContract.MovieTrailersEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_ID + "=?",
                    new String[]{mMovieId},
                    null);
        case REVIEW_LOADER:
            return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                    MovieDetailsContract.MovieReviewsEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[]{
                            MovieDetailsContract.MovieReviewsEntry._ID,
                            MovieDetailsContract.MovieReviewsEntry.COLUMN_AUTHOR,
                            MovieDetailsContract.MovieReviewsEntry.COLUMN_REVIEW,
                            MovieDetailsContract.MovieReviewsEntry.COLUMN_URL
                    },
                    MovieDetailsContract.MovieReviewsEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_ID + "=?",
                    new String[]{mMovieId},
                    null);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {

    switch (loader.getId()){

        case TRAILER_LOADER:
            reviewAdapter.swapCursor(data);
            break;

        case REVIEW_LOADER:
            reviewAdapter.swapCursor(data);
            break;
    }

}
```

Adapter:

```
public class ReviewAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

public ReviewAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    if(cursor.getColumnName(1).equals(MovieDetailsContract.MovieReviewsEntry.COLUMN_AUTHOR)) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.review_container, parent, false);
        ReviewViewHolder reviewViewHolder = new ReviewViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(reviewViewHolder);
    }else{
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.trailer_container, parent, false);
        TrailerViewHolder viewHolder = new TrailerViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    if(cursor.getColumnName(1).equals(MovieDetailsContract.MovieReviewsEntry.COLUMN_AUTHOR)) {
        ReviewViewHolder reviewViewHolder = (ReviewViewHolder) view.getTag();
        reviewViewHolder.reviewAuthorTxt.setText(cursor.getString(1));
        reviewViewHolder.reviewContentTxt.setText(cursor.getString(2));
        reviewViewHolder.reviewUrlTxt.setText(cursor.getString(3));
    }else{
        TrailerViewHolder trailerViewHolder = (TrailerViewHolder) view.getTag();
        trailerViewHolder.key = cursor.getString(1);
        trailerViewHolder.trailerNameTxt.setText(cursor.getString(2));
    }

}

public static class ReviewViewHolder {
    public final TextView reviewAuthorTxt;
    public final TextView reviewContentTxt;
    public final TextView reviewUrlTxt;

    public ReviewViewHolder(View v){
        reviewAuthorTxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.reviewAuthorTxt);
        reviewContentTxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.reviewContentTxt);
        reviewUrlTxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.reviewUrlTxt);
    }
}

public static class TrailerViewHolder {
    public final TextView trailerNameTxt;
    public String key;

    public TrailerViewHolder(View v){
        trailerNameTxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.trailerTxt);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Yes, code is required :)

Comment: If you are using the same `CursorAdapter` to render the contents of each cursor, use [a `MergeCursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MergeCursor.html) to combine the two cursors, once both have arrived from their loaders. Then, use the `MergeCursor` with your `CursorAdapter`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks. I posted the code as per Laurent. Could you please provide an example code with MergeCursor in this case